# How to make inSequence without send

Tags: esb, wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

I have this WSO2 ESB proxy:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sid008" transports="http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>

            <switch source="get-property('inquiryId')">
                        <log level="full"/>
                <case regex="">

                        <send/>

                </case>
                 <default>

                 </default>
             </switch>

        </inSequence>

        <outSequence>                      
<....some processing..>
            <send/>

        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL key="CommonService.wsdl">
        <resource location="request.xsd" key="request.xsd"/>
        <resource location="response.xsd" key="response.xsd"/>
        <resource location="SMEV.xsd" key="SMEV.xsd"/>
        <resource location="statusAndError.xsd" key="statusAndError.xsd"/>
    </publishWSDL>
</proxy>
```

In this proxy in default case doesn't run `outSequence` without send mediator. How can I do it without send mediator

Comment: In general, if inSequence doesn't specify a send mediator, then, the message received by WSO2 ESB will be dropped at the end of inSequence. Since the request message doesn't really go in to an endpoint mentioned in the proxy config, there's really no response to process in outSequence. What would be your usecase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this config for :

```xml
<default>
    <... some processing ...>
    <header action="remove" name="To"/>
    <property action="set" name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <send/>
</default>
```

With this config, you'll send response to client directly from inSequence part (you won't get into outSequence).

Answer (score 1):

The rational behind In and Out sequence is:

In seq : When a message comes to a proxy service from a client, it always goes to the In sequence.

Out Seq: When a proxy service sends a message out from ESB to a backend service, the response will always come to Out seq (Unless specify the sequence using receiving seq.)

Hope this helps.